# Rally custom app creation using node.js step by step

Tags: javascript, node.js, rally

I am very new to Rally.
I want to create a custom application using node.js toolkit.
In this application I want to retrieve iteration details like StartDate and EndDate and display them in HTML.

I was unable to find step-by-step guide to do this.

I was able to good example at https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide, however I don't understand how to make custom application out of it(to use within Dashboard as custom HTML).

Please suggest how to achieve this or if this is not the right approach please suggest alternative to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node toolkit is great for writing integrations that live outside of Agile Central.

If you'd like to display something within a Custom HTML panel on a dashboard or custom page in Agile Central you'll need to write an app using the [App SDK](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

so I started on the a similar journey really and came across the

[RallyCommunity/GettingStarted](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/GettingStarted) Guides..

Published on GH by [David Thomas](https://github.com/davidpthomas)

This really helped me push through the learning curve and once you start pulling out the debugger it gets clearer and clearer especially if you tie that back to the https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ documentation..

I'd also recommend hanging around the [AC SDK](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#) & [Sencha ExtJS 4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/) docs..

Feel free to pull this apart and have a look at a [simple data store example](https://github.com/cookra/Agile-Central-Store-Stub)

To push the output into HTML there are various ways to do this using fly if needed or direct into the xtype's HTML property...